# Okay to let the value in a field indicate what table to reference?

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-design

I'm working on building a database for a long-term plant breeding project. One of the needs of the project will be to be able to take an ID associated with some plant tissue sample, and get back the physical and genetic history of that sample. There are many possible courses this history may take. For instance, a tissue sample will always have come from an individual plant, and that plant will have come from some kind of propagule (seed or one of a couple types of clones). But that propagule may have been generated in-house, or it may have come from a wild population, or it may have been sent by another organization. In the first case we would want to go to the Accessions table next and then pull out pedigree information. In the second case we would want to pull out whatever information we have on where, when, how and by who it was collected.

The solution I have come up with for this is for each table that is associated with a stage in this history to have one column indicating the table associated with the previous stage of its history and then another column indicating the ID of the associated parent record. The idea being that I can then construct SQL strings in VBA that successively go deeper into the physical history until we hit a null value for the column that indicates the table of the parent record or reach some specified length of history. At that point we output the results.

I familiarized myself with the first three normal forms as described on Wikipedia. And I don't see anything inherent to this structure that violates those principles. But I can't help but feel like it is sloppy to use the values in a table to tell you what other table(s) to include in your query. I also tried googling various terms, but didn't find anything remotely along this lines.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could verify that this practice is accepted and non-problematic. Or if it is problematic, what is the problem with a structure like this?

I'm using Access 2013 if that is relevant.

EDIT: More information on the details of the structure I have in mind.

The way I have it laid out on paper right now is using automatically incremented integers as the primary keys for any of the tables that don't have concatenated keys. So I have tblSamples with an auto incremented Sample_ID as primary key. The table also has Plant_ID as a foreign key. The foreign key is used to put the table in a many to one relationship with tblPlants. tblPlants also has an autonumber primary key. It has a foreign key called Accession_ID, which is in a many to one relationship with the Accessions table. The Accessions table has an autonumber primary key. But then the next relevant piece of information may come from either the InHouseAccessions table or from the OutsideGermplasm table.

If I understand correctly, Smandoli suggests that if possible, I should change the structure so that there is no need to use VBA to set off the appropriate chain of queries. Great suggestion. I am definitely going to think about elegant ways to avoid the VBA. I believe GSerg and Jo are suggesting that rather than have a value in a single column indicate which query should come next that I could let the presence of a non-null value in a foreign key column (and the fact that the other contender columns have null values) indicate which query to execute next. I considered this, but then thought that using the one column would be simpler. Perhaps there are benefits I am overlooking to the approach GSerg and Jo suggest, or maybe I misunderstood even more profoundly.

Comment: I would assume the possible tables have different structure, so the code that reads them must not only take the name of the table, but also be aware about all possible table names and know what columns to query from each. At that point you don't need to store table *names* in source table's columns. Instead have columns like `AccessionID`, `SampleID` etc, and join the respective tables on these values provided they are not null.

Comment: You are right, the tables would have different structure, so the right query to run next differs substantially depending on the table indicated. I was hoping that by indicating the reference table explicitly I could run just the correct query without making the system try all the possible reference tables. I suppose the same thing could be accomplished by only running the query that corresponds to the xxxID field with a non-null value, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in principle.  But I would want to check carefully for a better approach -- one that allows you to leave out VBA, of course.  This would require looking at the data.

This is how I would imagine the solution you are attempting:

```
========   ==============
Specimen   History
  ID ------ ID
========    Sequence       (perhaps date-time)
            Event-Phase    (used to indicate table)
            Event-Phase-ID (index within the table)
            ==============
```

### After reviewing your two comments below:

I believe you'll find a precedent in *Product Design Management* (PDM), relating to software for manufacturing which relies on so-called *Bills of Materials* (BOMs).  BOMs must employ a hierarchical data structure, which is clearly indicated for reporting the history of propagulae.

MS Access is tolerably good at handling this sort of thing.  But hierarchical data structures are inherently difficult.  (Challenges for handling BOMs have resulted in some big innovations in database management).  Furthermore your variable paths for propagation are beyond regular PDM.  You are in for a lot of learning and effort, in my estimation.  And some VBA.

Comment: That is about what I had in mind, but I was imagining adding the Event-Phase and Event-Phase-ID columns to every table where the histories could diverge. For instance, a plant may have been part of a group of seedlings without any individual existence in the database before being "promoted" to the status of an individual. But another possibility is that it was a seed in a bag. The bag had an existence in the database, the seed just contributed to the quantity of seed associated with the bag. So the way I envision it... I'll describe more below.

Comment: The user selects the starting point by inputting the sample type (indicates starting table) and the sample_id (indicates the row of this chronologically last stage in history). Then based on the value in the ParentTable column of that row one of a few different queries is run, which pull certain columns depending on the parent table, and outputs them possibly as one string structured along the lines of what would be said in a paper about the physical history of the sample. One of the columns selected would indicate the next query to run. The process repeats until ParentTable is null.

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented on, you shouldn't need the table names to be held in a column.

I would suggest you read up on the concept of primary keys and foreign keys, if you haven't done so already. Essentially, each row in a table should be uniquely identified by one column, or by a particular collection of columns - this is the primary key for that table. When a child table exists, it can have the column(s) related with its parent's primary key, and these can be used to join. Primary and foreign keys can be enforced in many database systems; I'm not sure about Access, but you can implement this without database enforcement.

The pattern you are then *almost* following is the use of surrogate keys. This is where - having identified the natural primary key, you add a new column with a value (usually an integer) which will be unique within that table. Each surrogate key stands in for a natural primary key. If you were enforcing primary keys in the database, you would define the surrogate key column as the primary key for that table. The child table would then only ever need one extra column to point to a parent table.

As far as how you know what to link to - if you can enforce your primary and foreign keys in your DBMS, then this is self-documenting as a part of your database schema. If you cannot - and even if you can - careful naming of tables and primary key columns will help. For instance, the Plant table could have PlantId as its primary key column. The TissueSample table would have TissueSampleId as a primary key, and PlantId as a foreign key to the Plant table.